# how to refresh the asp.net Label every second automatically using Java script instead ajax?

Tags: javascript, asp.net

how to refresh the asp.net Label every second automatically using Java script instead ajax?

Comment: Do it the same way as you would with ajax, then drop the ajax.

Comment: with out timer control how to do this..

Comment: Does the value to refresh it with have to come from the server or is it based on something else on the page (textbox value or something)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ajax is javascript in combination with a webrequest, so if you don't want to use ajax but only javascript the data has to come from somewhere else...

Put this at the end of your page and replace Label1 with the name of your Label for a nice working digital clock:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function updateLabel(){
    document.getElementById('<%= Label1.ClientID %>').innerHTML = new Date(); 
    // replace new Date() with your updated value
    setTimeout("updateLabel()",1000);
}
updateLabel();
</script>
```